# Session timeout during connecting Hotmail account with Java mail API

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail, hotmail

For connecting with hotmail account through java mail API , I m setting these properties

```
pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "true");
pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3s.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY); 
pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3s.socketFactory.fallback", "false");    
pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3s.port", "995");   
pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3s.socketFactory.port", "995");

Properties pop3Props = new Properties();
pop3Props.setProperty("mail.pop3s.port",  "995");

Session session = Session.getInstance(pop3Props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");
store.connect(host, 995, username, password);
```

I am able to login into my hotmail account and do other operations(send/receive) but
  after some time (I think) session time out happens i.e not able to connect with hotmail
  server.
  Later sometime onward again it is working fine ( i m able to connect with hotmail
  server).
  And I checked in my code that whenever I open a new connection , I m closing it also.
  Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Are you leaving the connection open for long periods of time without doing anything?

Are you opening and closing the connection frequently over short periods of time?

Servers have lots of ways of preventing you from "abusing" their resources.  You may be running into one of them.

Or, maybe you have an unreliable network connection?

See the JavaMail FAQ for [debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug); the debug output might provide more clues as to why it's failing.

Also see the list of [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes); you can simplify your code.

Comment: hello hannon ,thanks for reply I am not opening the connections for long periods of time.
But yes I am opening and closing the connection frequently (say for each mail feature like compose, reply, fwd etc I open new connection after that again close).

If this is the reason,  should I have to maintain the connection for longer time ??

Comment: It depends a lot on your application.  If there's a natural sequence of events that occur together, and you can keep the connection open for that entire sequence, that would be best.  If each "mail feature" for which you open a connection is based on a human doing something, it's usually difficult to do too many operations in a short period of time.  If you're doing automated mail processing, it's more likely that you'll exceed the limit.  You'll probably need to experiment to see what Hotmail will allow.